# Get Id of an dynamically created javascript element

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a list which is dynamically created like this:

```
inner += "<li class='linkstyl'> <a href='#"+tot+"' id='a"+tot
         + "' style='text-decoration:none'  onclick='addpoint("
         + results[0].geometry.location.lat()+","
         + results[0].geometry.location.lng()+")'> " 
         + results[0].formatted_address+"</a></li>"
```

Then I am using:

```
$("#showaddress").html(inner);  // to insert it inside <ul> with id as  showaddress .
```

My problems is that when I try to `getElementById` of the this dynamically created elements
it returns me a null value.
How do I reference this dynamically created elements?

Comment: can you show your code to get this element? Why aren't you using a jquery selector?

Comment: Please also show the code you use to call getElementById

Answer (score 0):

That code works fine. Perhaps you are trying to use `getElementById()` before the ajax request completes. At that point the elements won't be on the page still. Otherwise perhaps your `tot` variable doesn't contain what you think it does.

Try checking those two things over.

Comment: The inner elelment is created after the ajax call and tot just conatins numerical value +1,+2,+3..... like that.I view sourced 
the code , the elements are created as expected .

Answer (score 0):

javascript is asynchronous.
May be the elements are not yet available when you are trying to get them.
Try the selector in the callback itself where you get the response from the geocoder.

Comment: *javascript is asynchronous*... that is a bit too general, if not wrong. There are operations which are asynchronous, such as `setTimeout`, `setInterval` or Ajax calls, but apart from that, the execution of JavaScript is very linear.